# The resolution of an animation with matplotlib on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I generate an image sequence, convert it to a movie with matplotlib. Then, this movie is shown in jupyter notebook. The problem is that the resolution of the movie shown in jupyter notebook is rather poor. My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tifffile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from Ipython.display import HTML
stack = tifffile.imread("some image stack")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_axis_off()
im = ax.imshow(stack[:, :, 0])

def init():
    im.set_data(stack[:, :, 0])
    return [im]

def animate(i):
    im.set_array(stack[:, :, i])
    return [im]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=stack.shape[2], interval=1000, blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

I did not find any options in matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation() or in matplotlib.animation.to_html5_video() that can change the bitrate or something of the animation. Is there any way to increase the resolution?

Comment: If you only want to show the animation, you can use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend an show the animation directly without exporting it to html5-video.

Comment: Oh, did not know that.. This is convenient!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the bitrate through `anim.to_html5_video()` but you can if exporting to disk with `anim.save(bitrate=1024)`.

See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save

For a high resolution embedded video use:

```py
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```